# How can I remove the spaces from these numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a table (t1) in my database which contain a column called "MealPlan".

This column contains a list of strings (extract below):

```
                        MealPlan
Sansrepas315€/pers.=630€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner

Sansrepas394€/pers.=787€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner

Sansrepas547€/pers.=1 093€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner

Sansrepas547€/pers.=1 093€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner

Sansrepas700€/pers.=1 400€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner

Sansrepas328€/pers.=656€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner
```

I need to extract the numbers between the characters **=** and **€**

I have the following codes in place which does exactly what I need:

```
SUBSTRING(MealPlan,LEN(LEFT(MealPlan,CHARINDEX('=', MealPlan)+1)),LEN(MealPlan) - LEN(LEFT(MealPlan,CHARINDEX('=', MealPlan))) - LEN(RIGHT(MealPlan,CHARINDEX('€', (REVERSE(MealPlan)))))) AS [Price]
```

After running the above my column "Price" appear as follows:

```
Price
630
787
1 093
1 093
1 400
656
```

However, I want to get rid of that space in the numbers where a thousand digit is present.

My expected output:

```
   Price
    630
    787
    1093
    1093
    1400
    656
```

I have tried the following but it is not working:

```
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(MealPlan,LEN(LEFT(MealPlan,CHARINDEX('=', MealPlan)+1)),LEN(MealPlan) - LEN(LEFT(MealPlan,CHARINDEX('=', MealPlan))) - LEN(RIGHT(MealPlan,CHARINDEX('€', (REVERSE(MealPlan)))))), ' ','') AS [Price2]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it definately one space?

Comment: If it were just a single space what you've tried would have worked. So its something else.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav When I copy the output and paste it in Excel, it appears to be one space (a single backstroke removes it).

Comment: Look at the character code for the position of the "space" and see what it is.

Comment: Try cut'n'pasting the space character from the file into the SQL query, in case it's a different kind of space?

Comment: It could be Non-breaking space 0xA0 as well.

Comment: Unicode has a bunch of other spaces, too; wider, narrower, various special kinds

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your query in my sample database and it is working fine..

```
select 
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Description,
LEN(LEFT(Description,CHARINDEX('=', Description)+1)),
LEN(Description) - LEN(LEFT(Description,CHARINDEX('=', Description))) - LEN(RIGHT(Description,CHARINDEX('€', (REVERSE(Description)))))
), ' ','') AS [Description]
from Worker
```

Comment: Thanks but not at my end.

Answer (score 0):

Table #a1

```
| MealPlan |
| -------- |
| Sansrepas315€/pers.=630€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner   |
| Sansrepas394€/pers.=787€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner   |
| Sansrepas547€/pers.=1 093€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner |
```

Query

```
SELECT 
        REPLACE(
            SUBSTRING(MealPlan,CHARINDEX('=', MealPlan)+1, CHARINDEX('=',REVERSE(MealPlan)) - CHARINDEX('€',REVERSE(MealPlan)) -1 )  
            ,' ', ''
        )
        as value
FROM #a1
```

results

| value |
| --- |
| 630 |
| 787 |
| 1093 |

Comment: Not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution about "cut and paste" provided by Jiří Baum above did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to tokenize a string of characters by using XML and XQuery.

No need to parse string and call multiple functions: `SUBSTRING(), CHARINDEX(), PATINDEX(), LEN(), REVERSE()`, etc.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, MealPlan NVARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl (MealPlan) VALUES
(N'Sansrepas315€/pers.=630€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner'),
(N'Sansrepas394€/pers.=787€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner'),
(N'Sansrepas547€/pers.=1 093€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner'),
(N'Sansrepas547€/pers.=1 093€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner'),
(N'Sansrepas700€/pers.=1 400€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner'),
(N'Sansrepas328€/pers.=656€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '='
    , @euro CHAR(1) = '€';


SELECT t.* 
    , REPLACE(c.value('(/root/r[3]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)'),SPACE(1),'') AS Price
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(MealPlan,@euro,@separator), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| ID |                          MealPlan                          | Result |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | Sansrepas315€/pers.=630€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner   |    630 |
|  2 | Sansrepas394€/pers.=787€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner   |    787 |
|  3 | Sansrepas547€/pers.=1 093€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner |   1093 |
|  4 | Sansrepas547€/pers.=1 093€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner |   1093 |
|  5 | Sansrepas700€/pers.=1 400€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner |   1400 |
|  6 | Sansrepas328€/pers.=656€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner   |    656 |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
Declare @MealPlan as varchar(250) = 'Sansrepas547€/pers.=1 093€pour2pers.Devis/RésaSelectionner'

Select Replace(
          SUBSTRING(@MealPlan,
                    CharIndex('=', @MealPlan)+1, 
                    CharIndex(')',Replace(@MealPlan, '€p', ')'))- CharIndex('=', @MealPlan)-1 ),
          ' ', '')
```

**Output:**

[image]

Let me know if this doesn't work or you have a problem understanding the query.